# How to center image and text inside a block

Tags: html, css

How do you center an image with text inside a block?

I know you can center a block inside another block by giving the latter a fixed width and `margin: auto`. However, I don't know the dimensions of text beforehand (actual text content may vary).

[image]

The CSS I have got so far:

```
.outer {
    width: 400px;
}

.outer table {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer table td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.outer table td p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: if you provide the html also

Comment: What's your HTML structure?

Comment: Provide a fiddle please :)

Comment: can you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Do you need both vertical and horyzontal centering?

Comment: Guys, HTML can be anything you want. I use a table – http://jsfiddle.net/Nvs2T/. @MiheyEgoroff, yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jb5EJ/1/)

Here is my css:

```
.block {
  text-align: center;
}
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
```

**Explanation about :before element:**

This is an invisible element pseudo element, which is used for better vertical centering: it emulates a 0-sized inline-block element, which, in conjunction with normal inline-block element (`.centered`) allows us to use `vertical-align`.

**UPDATE:** 
You can set height to `.block` to see how it will be centered vertically:
http://jsfiddle.net/jb5EJ/5/

**UPDATE 2:** Is this closer: http://jsfiddle.net/jb5EJ/13/

Comment: Thanks! I've edited it a little (http://jsfiddle.net/jb5EJ/3/) and it seems to do what I want!

Comment: But you deleted .block:after, thats why it want work perfectly.

Comment: I can't see the difference with or without `.block:before`, could you explain what it does? Anyway, marking accepted, thank you!

Comment: I've updated my post with the answer to your questions. You're welcome :3

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link. I hope you will get the solution.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

**TLDR:** with only this CSS you can position an element in absolute center (both horizontally and vertically):

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not the full answer. The point is to position 2 elements, -  image and text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle;`   to `img` too....also, i would suggest to add `height` to `outer` class

```
<img src="some_src" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> I have some text too
```

[**demo to get u started**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fds3H/)